# Run simple C++ OpenCV on Mac Terminal

Tags: c++, xcode, opencv

I'm a complete beginner with cpp and opencv. I would like to compile and run this simple Program that lets me display an image. This works if I run the code inside XCode but if I try it using clang in the console it throws me a

```
linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I had add these "linker flags" in Xcode to get opencv to run so I assume I need to somehow install them globally too. HHow would I achieve this?

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {

if (argc != 2) {
    cout << "Bitte zu ladendes Bild als Parameter angeben." << endl;
    return -1;
}

Mat image;
image = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);

if (!image.data) {
    cout <<  "Bild " << argv[1] << " wurde nicht gefunden." << std::endl ;
    return -1;
}

namedWindow("OpenCV Window", WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
imshow("OpenCV Window", image);

cout << "Image width: " << image.cols << ", image height: " << 
image.rows << endl;

waitKey(0);

return 0;
}
```

These are the Linker Flags inside Xcode:

```
-lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgcodecs -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_shape -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_video -lopencv_videoio -lopencv_videostab
```